# key-value pair, having arrays as values

Tags: javascript, arrays, keyvaluepair

`'key': {[value0, value1], [value2, value3]}`

Is this kind of key-value available with javascript?
I would like to update those `[value_n, value_m]` to my original `{[value0, value1], [value2, value3]}`

So what I expect is this : `'key': {[value0, value1], [value2, value3]}`

To do this, I tried using `value.push([value_n, value_m])` but this didn't work.

So to sum up,

1. Is there a way to make `'key': {[value0, value1], [value2, value3]}`?
2. How do I put in more arrays to existing value?

Thank you in advance!!! :)

Comment: Would `{key:[[0,1],[2,3]]}`work?

Comment: Your structure is not possible, because `{}` notates object, but you have it in array form. Proper structure would be `{"key": [[v0, v1], [v2, v3]}`, then you can do `myVar.key.push([v1, v2])`